# Refused исключения для локального хоста

Tags: c++, poco

Пытаюсь освоить poco. Но сбрасывается соединение к локальному хосту.
Нашел на гите [открытый вопрос](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/issues/2226) по этой проблеме, где указывается одно из возможных решений. Объявить `POCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4` для приоритет IPv4 адресов, но ошибка `Connection refused` продолжает бросаться. Есть ли обходное решение данной проблемы?

```
#define POCO_SOCKETADDRESS_PREFER_IPv4

#include <sstream>
#include <string>

#include "Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h"

void test() {
    Poco::Net::SocketAddress server{Poco::Net::AddressFamily::IPv4, "127.0.0.1", 80};
    Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session{server};
    Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request{Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, "/", Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1};

    request.setKeepAlive(true);
    request.setContentLength(/*somesize*/);
    request.setContentType("application/json");

    std::ostream& o = session.sendRequest(request); // Exception
}

int main() {
    test();
    return 0;   
}
```

**UPD**:
Как я раньше не попробовал порты отличные от 80 и 8080. Но, суть осталась такая же. Браузер может свободно обращаться к 80 и 8080 на локальном хосте, но Poco все еще отказывается подключаться к этим портам.

Comment: Ваш `server` - это адрес. А вам нужен настоящий сервер, который будет отвечать на запросы по этому адресу.

Comment: @VTT, у меня локальны php-сервер запущен был  на 80. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну еще странно что у вас `setContentLength` `setContentType` c json, а запрос GET

Comment: @VTT, там без разницы как отправлять json. PHP обрабатывает. Проблема и без всего этого есть.